# form textfield name -value changed and does not validate any more

Tags: forms

i have a checkout-page (drupal commerce) form with an address section generated by the module addressfield.
currently all text-inputfields have this markup-structure:

`<input class="last-name" id="edit-last-name" name="customer_profile_billing[commerce_customer_address][und][0][last_name]">`

class + id + name

in this config they validate.

if i change the value of the name attribute the form doesnt validate anymore, the form says:

> field XY is required

the form-validator obviously doesnt recognise my inputs.

question: how can i get the validation process to work with a modified `name` attribute?

Comment: The real question is "why do you need to modify the name attribute?" :) It's probably going to be easier to find a way around _that_ issue than it is to override the core form validation. Are you changing the name to make the element easier to find in jQuery code for example?

Comment: if would i could leave it like this, i dont need this name attribute anywere. but, i like things clean. i cant get it why `form()` gets upset if i change that attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It all happens in [`drupal_validate_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_validate_form/7).

> Validates user-submitted form data in the $form_state array.

If I could offer some advice - have a re-think. Changing the name attribute of form elements, especially on those that are part of field widget forms, is a good way to get unexpected results. The `name` on an input is completely irrelevant to the page, so changing it doesn't actually get you anything. If you're trying to change it so you can target the elements using JS, for example, I'd advise changing your JS code rather than the form markup. Trust me when I say it will be easier.

The only valid situation I know of to override the name of an element is when you need to provide multiple submit buttons on a single form that carry out the same action, but in a different context.

Comment: thank you clive for your professional comment on this. i know, the `name` attribute is not relevant for the page, i just want to know were these amounts of ids, classes and divs come from and which of them are essential to the site and which are "just in case someone could need them". also i want to learn how much control can i have over the form markup.

Comment: @user19578 Short answer to that is: you can have 100% control over your form markup, but the more you change from the default, the more code you'll have to write. There isn't a single place where classes, ids, attributes, etc get set; that can happen in any number of theme functions, element theme functions, element process functions, theme preprocess functions, form theme/preprocess functions, and a ton of other places. You really have to follow the trail down for the specific form you're dealing with. After a while you just develop an instinct of where to look

Comment: yes i unterstand what you mean. 100% control will not be my goal but i am not happy with the standard markup of `form.inc` so i digg in and learn a bit how this thing works but this `name` thing is not so easy. seems before validating the `$form_state` get cached or something. maybe you can leave some words on the validating process pls?

Comment: That's quite tricky, it's a long process :) Could you outline exactly what you'd like to accomplish, and maybe why as well? It would just help to understand what needs to happen, and make it easier to know which functions to push you towards. If you'd be so good as to edit the question and add that information I'd be glad to revise my answer with the extra info. To start, [`_form_builder_handle_input_element()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/_form_builder_handle_input_element/7) will probably be of interest, that's where the `#name` property is set for elements

Comment: extend my question description for maybe a better understanding.